# Can't use python 2.7 with cygwin

Tags: python, python-2.7, cygwin

I'm trying to use python 2.7 with my Cygwin terminal. I'm not great with Cygwin/installing packages, but this is what I've tried so far.

I've reran the Cygwin installer and selected the python27 package, but that didn't seem to work. I've downloaded and installed python 2.7 from the python website.

Running any python command gets me "-bash: python: command not found"

Running python3 --version gets me "Python 3.6.10"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install also `python2` package

It includes the needed links:

```
python2: Python 2 language interpreter

2020-05-23 09:41           0 usr/bin/pydoc -> pydoc2.7
2020-05-23 09:41           0 usr/bin/pydoc2 -> pydoc2.7
2020-05-23 09:41           0 usr/bin/python -> python2.7.exe
2020-05-23 09:41           0 usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7.exe
2020-05-23 09:42          45 usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
2020-05-23 09:42          46 usr/share/man/man1/python2.1.gz
```

as mentioned on:
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86/python2/python2-2.7.18-1

Comment: Make sure you know which python you are executing - either cygwin or windows python 2 or 3. Use the `which exe-name` to see what gets executed when you try to run python2 or python3 in cygwin. `which python` should say /usr/bin/python or /bin/python and `which python3` should say ./usr/bin/python3 or /bin/python3. If you get something else you don't have the right cygwin packages installed so you are getting some windows python.

Comment: The package python2 is not available in newer cygwin versions (as of 2023)

Comment: @wolfrevo time to move on python 3. Latest packaged for cygwin is 3.9.16 (with 3.9.18 in test) https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2023-December/011437.html

Comment: @matzeri You're absolutely right. We are since long on Python 3. But we have also lots of scripts running on Python 2 that we cannot yet afford to refactor.

Comment: 2to3 is your friend